# What is this Islamic sect mentioned by Bayle

Tags: islamic-philosophy, sects

In his Critical and Philosophical dictionary Bayle mentions an Islamic sect that calls itself "Ehl Eltahkik or men of truth, men of certainty, who believe that there is nothing existent but the four elements which are God, man and everything else".

I tried to find some historicalinformation about this sect but in vain. I would appreciate any help in locating some other references or explanations.

Comment: I suspect "Ehl Eltahkik" is an attempted transliteration of the Arabic "اهل التحقيق". I'm not fluent in Arabic to know if searching for that brings up anything useful though.

Comment: The same phrase could also be transliterated as "[Ahl al-tahqiq](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ahl+al-tahqiq%22)" or "[Ahlul tahqiq](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ahlul+tahqiq%22)" which provide a fair number of Google hits that "[Ehl Eltahkik](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Ehl+Eltahkik%22)" doesn't. Not an answer, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: أهل التحقيق is used for various people because of its literal meanings, I doubt that you will be able to identify an obscure sect from that alone. Maybe details of the beliefs would be useful.

Comment: Ah, thanks these comments are already useful.